# Conformal map, unit disk to slit $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find a conformal map $f(z)$ which maps the unit disk D bijectively onto the whole complex plane minus the non-negative real axis, and which in addition satisfies:
>   \begin{equation} \lim_{z\rightarrow -1} f(z)=0 \quad , \quad f(0)=-4 \end{equation}

Finding the original conformal map is not difficult: you first map the unit disk onto the upper half plane with

\begin{equation} w= i\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)\end{equation}

And then use the squaring map to take the half plane to the whole plane minus the negative real axis, giving us

\begin{equation} y= -\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)^2\end{equation}

By multiplying 4 to the above equation , we satisfy $f(0)=-4$. But how can we satisfy the condition of the limit at -1 equaling 0?

Thank you!

Comment: How about $f(z) = -4\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)^2$?

Comment: Oh sorry yes i meant to say "by multiplying by 4" not subtracting 4. But does this give our limit that we want?

Comment: Or I guess, why did you change $1-z$ to $1+z$ and vice versa?

Comment: Since the nonnegative real axis contains $0,$ what sense is $f(0)$ supposed to make?

Comment: @zhw 0 is the center of the unit disk. ;o)

Comment: @jgcello I swapped them in order that $f(-1)$ exists and is zero.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Thanks, dumb mistake by me.